# How to create a range domain in ArcGIS with an interval of 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, domains

I need to create a range domain in a file geodatabase. The user will be able to select a value ranging from 0 and to 200 with an interval of 10. For example, 0, 10, 20, ..., 200.

How can I make and configure a domain type like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a range domain which only has discrete values - for that you need a coded value domain. See [a quick tour of attribute domains](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001s00000001000000).

> There are two types of attribute domains:
>
> - Range domains—A range domain specifies a valid **range** of values for a    numeric attribute.
> - Coded domains— Coded value domains specify a valid **set** of values for an attribute.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question. What if a range domain contains thousands of discrete values? Is there a programmatic way?

Comment: Any more than a dozen values in a list is bad, it takes so long to find the value you're after! That said, I don't know an easy way around this so that might be the only way. There is Add Coded Value to Domain http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000001v000000 which you can iterate in arcpy.

Comment: @alextc That should be a separate question but I would use arcpy.da.InsertCursor with a loop to write a table that you convert with [Table To Domain](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000025000000).

Comment: From your other question it sounds like you're doing this in a web client - in that case you might be able to do something clever with type-ahead followed by some validation. Prompt the user with possible values as they start typing, and verify the value once they've entered something